# R script as cronjob not executing

Tags: r, ubuntu, amazon-ec2, cron

I've created a short R script that continuously downloads data from twitter using the streamR package. This script is supposed to run on a standard Amazon EC2 server running Ubuntu 14.04. When testing it in the standard command line, it runs fine. However, it is not run as specified in the cronjob. I used the following command:

```
sudo crontab -e
```

and then added the following line to the file

```
0 * * * * Rscript /home/mydirectory/docs/phd-research/data-collection/cron-script.R
```

in the hope that it would execute the R script every hour.

Is there anything I might have got wrong with the permissions? I've already checked that cron is running and I chmodded the directory the r script is supposed to write to to 775.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

OK - it turns out I used the wrong command to call up the crontab. The directory it was supposed to be working in was owned by `user` rather than `root`, so calling a root crontab didn't work. 
The proper command for editing the crontab is the following:

```
crontab -u user -e
```

The `Rscript` didn't require the full path, it worked with both.

Answer (score 0):

The `$PATH$` is not known (i.e. the directory of `Rscript` is not part of the standard `$PATH$`) during the execution of a cronjob. Writing the full path to `Rscript` will work:

```
0 * * * * /.../Rscript /home/mydirectory/docs/phd-research/data-collection/cron-script.R
```

Comment: Hi @jogo, thanks for your reply! I've changed the path and given it a try.

Comment: hi, sadly that didn't do the trick. I'm starting to think it must have something to do with the permissions. the cronjob is owned by root while the directory it's supposed to write to is owned by user, could that be the issue?

Comment: OK, turns out that was the issue!